# Java Class<T> static method forName() IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java

private static Importable getRightInstance(String s) throws Exception {
       Class c = Class.forName(s).asSubclass(Importable.class);
       Importable i = c.newInstance();
       return i;
    }

which i can also write

```
private static Importable getRightInstance(String s) throws Exception {
   Class<? extends Importable> c = (Class<? extends Importable>)Class.forName(s);
   Importable i = c.newInstance();
   return i;
}
```

or

```
private static Importable getRightInstance(String s) throws Exception {
   Class<?> c = Class.forName(s);
   Importable i = (Importable)c.newInstance();
   return i;
}
```

where Importable is an interface and s is a string representing an implementing class.
Well, in any case it gives the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class C1 has
interface Importable as super class
```

Here is the last snippet of the stack trace:

```
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
 at Importer.getRightImportable(Importer.java:33)
 at Importer.importAll(Importer.java:44)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Now, class C1 actually implemens Importable and i totally don't understand why it complaints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IncompatibleClassChangeError` means something is wrong with the class file that you're loading. In this case, it sounds like `Importable` was originally a class when `C1` was compiled, and now you've changed it to an interface. Since the JVM cares about the difference between `extends SomeClass` and `implements SomeInterface`, you'll need to recompile `C1` against the current `Importable` interface (and probably also change its code from `extends` to `implements`.

Comment: Hibernate has been known to throw this exception when switching when between certain incompatible versions.

Comment: yes, you are right. The issue was that i compiled C1 when Importable was an abstract class. Declaring that C1 implements Importable without recompile it, was useless. Thanks a bunch.